# Add selected cell title to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, uitableview

I wrote the code below to add all the titles of a UILabel for each cell in my tableview, however I am not sure how to proceed. I get errors because of the index part.

Thank you in advance

```
- (IBAction)addAllCellLabelNamesToList:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSMutableArray*selected=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i =0;i<[_mainTable numberOfRowsInSection:0];i++) {
        ListCell*cell=[_mainTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:i];//not usre what to put here
        if (!cell.isSelected) {//if selected add to array
            [selected addObject:cell.ingredientLabel.text];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewDataSource#tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` takes an `NSIndexPath` parameter, not a simple `int`.

Try the following code:

```
[_mainTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:i]]
```